# Is it possible to set Colspan/Rowspan for elements whose display is set to table-cell

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to set `Colspan/Rowspan` for elements whose display is set to table-cell. If it is how can you do this? I'm trying to write a JavaScript function which will make my layout. The function will take number of cells, rows and `colspan/rowspan` properties to make a layout.
I'm trying to achieve functionalities like here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KRyEL-T_wRU&feature=player_embedded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, there is no css alternative for col/row-span attributes.

Use real tables or grid systems (e.g. [960gs](http://960.gs/)) for tasks like this.